# Possible value of charges in motion of two charges

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, electrostatics, electrons, electric-current

> **Two small particles of charges equal in magnitude and opposite in sign, $q_1$ and $q_2$ have masses $m$ and $2m$ respectively. Initially the distance between the particles is $d$. Both have equal magnitude of velocity $v$. However the velocity of
> $2m$ is directed away from $m$ and velocity of $m$ is perpendicular to the line joining the two charges. In subsequent motion of particles, they are found to be at a distance of $3d$ from each other twice. Find the possible values of the charges of each particle.**

I noted that initially the charge with mass m will perform circular motion. But gradually the mutual electrostatic forces will change direction so motion will change. The external force of the system is zero, so the centre of mass will move with the same velocity ($V_{cm}$). However, I am unable to proceed further.

Comment: have you tried using the conservation laws?

Comment: I couldn't think where to apply them.